# How to format number in a Grafana table?

Tags: grafana

I'm displaying some data in a Grafana table and one of the columns is a number between 1 and 999999. I want it to be always displayed with six digits, with leading zeros, e.g. `012345`. How can I do this?

**Update:** My data source is ElasticSearch.

Comment: Depending on your datasource, this might be much easier to implement in the query than in Grafana

Comment: Thanks! My data source is ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was discussed [here](https://community.grafana.com/t/table-panel-trims-leading-or-0-characters-from-sql-string/38198), this can be resolved by adding a field override for the field, with “Unit” as “Misc → String”. You can follow this [link](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/configure-overrides/) for configuring field overrides

Comment: That's a different problem.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides If the data source is already sending data with leading zeros. you can use a string variable at grafana end to display them in the table. Sorry for not explaining this clearly in the previous post.

Comment: The value is a number. An integer.